# Dropping the index column from DataFrame in a .csv file in Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, csv

I have a python script here:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
import csv

df = pd.read_sql("""script_generator""", conn)

for count, row in df.iterrows():
    row.to_csv('generatedfile{}.sql'.format(count), index=False, index_label=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=' ')
```

and when I run it, it creates separate csv files that are formatted in sql.
The output looks like this in generatedfile2:

```
2
IF    EXISTS  (SELECT  *  FROM  sys.objects  WHERE  object_id  =  OBJECT_ID(N'table1')  AND  type  in  (N'U')) 
 
BEGIN 
 
        PRINT  'DROPPING  TABLE  [dbo].[table1]....' 
 
        DROP  TABLE  [dbo].[table1];   
 
END;
```

The rest of the files have this same format.
Is there any way I can change my code to get rid of the "2" at the beginning of the code? It won't run properly in SQL because of it. For some reason index_label=False won't get rid of it.
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You know what, this might be a bug! I do reproduce issue. Strange the defaults `index=True` and `index_label=None` leads with comma in .csv. Consider alerting authors on the [GitHub pandas dev page](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues). Be sure to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) with runnable code and small data sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running `DataFrame.iterrows`, `row` renders as a Pandas Series and not a Data Frame. So actually, you are running [**`Series.to_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_csv.html).

```py
for count, row in df.iterrows():
    print(type(row))

# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
...
```

However, this method is not useful to iterate off a single column.  Instead, consider simply looping directly on the values of the column (assumed to be entirely your SQL statement). With each iteration, create the corresponding csv file with typical `open` + `write` methods. Use `enumerate` for sequential numbering for file suffixes.

```py
for count, val in enumerate(df['sql_string_column']):
    with open('generatedfile{}.sql'.format(count), 'w') as f:
        f.write(val)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I was able to get rid of the index number with your method. My column doesn't have a column name so I wrote:

for i, val in enumerate(df['']):
    with open('generatedfile{}.sql', 'w') as f:
        f.write(val)

but it only creates one .sql file now, which is just named generatedfile{}.sql. Is having a blank column name messing it up?